# Python Selenium how to get text from a div after a span

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to select text within a div after a span.

Source looks like this:

```
<div id="citation">
    <cite>Journal</cite>
    ", "
    <span class="year">2014</span>
    ", "
    <span class="volume">100</span>
    " (4), pp 100-200"
</div>
```

I only want the " (4), pp 100-200".

I know how to get text out of the entire div, or each span, but how do I grab only the last text? This XPATH will not work. ISSUE_XPATH = "//*[@id=\"citation\"]/text()[3]"

And shows this error message:

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: {"errorMessage":"The result of the xpath expression \"//*[@id=\"citation\"]/text()[3]\" is: [object Text]. It should be an element."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `//*[@id=\"citation\"]/text()[3]` is not going to work in selenium - you can only target actual elements, not text nodes.

What I would do in this case is to additionally use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) HTML parser which would help to locate a specific text sibling after the `span` element with `class="volume"`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

citation = driver.find_element_by_id("citation")
html = citation.get_attribute("outerHTML")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
desired_text = soup.find("span", class_="volume").next_sibling
print(desired_text)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that code, but I keep getting this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_sibling'` I'm not sure why.

Comment: @moglido what if you print `html` - what do you get? Thanks.

Comment: printing html gives me the html from the div above. however, there are no quotation marks around the text in the terminal output.

Comment: @moglido weird, should work as is. Okay, could you post your complete code so that I can try to reproduce the issue? Thanks.

Comment: python file [link](https://gist.github.com/tsboom/a5ccc73c6f9e2ef66392ba13e0d5c829).  I'm looking at lines 232-240. page source (line 3717) [link](https://gist.github.com/tsboom/fb0d77560dfc975195c788e058f42194)

Comment: printing html shows this `<div id="citation"><cite>ACS Catal.</cite>, <span class="citation_year">2015</span>, <span class="citation_volume">5</span> (9), pp 5436–5452</div>`, but `issue_text = soup.find("span", class_="volume")` results in `None`. Oh wow I changed class to the correct name, `volume` to `citation_volume`, and now it works! Typo!

Comment: @moglido glad you've figured that out!

Comment: thanks so much for your help! this isn't the first time you've helped me a lot!